# MySQL ENUM value is not saved when calling stored procedure through PDO

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo, enums

I have created this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LogAdd(
    IN log_title VARCHAR(128),
    IN log_type ENUM('message','warning','error'),
    IN log_info TEXT
) 
DETERMINISTIC 
MODIFIES SQL DATA 
COMMENT 'Insert a new log entry' 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `tbl_logs` (
        `title`,
        `type`,
        `info`
    )
    VALUES (
        log_title,
        log_type,
        log_info
    );
END
```

which works when executed with data directly added in the query. But when I bind parameters, the `type` column, which is of `ENUM` type, is not saved (is empty). I can see that the value is sent as a string:

```
$stmt = $pdo -> prepare("CALL LogAdd(?, ?, ?)");
$stmt -> bindParam(1, 'Message title');
$stmt -> bindParam(2, 'message');
$stmt -> bindParam(3, 'Message information');

$stmt -> execute();
```

Why isn't the `ENUM` value saved?

Comment: turn on strict errors, and see if the insert causes an error. if you insert a value that's not listed in the enum, default is to insert an empty string and not throw an error. what you see as `'message'` in the bind call, may be something wonky like `message<invisible unicode char>`

Comment: The second argument to `bindParam` needs to be a variable, you can't put literal strings there. Please show your actual code.

Comment: If you want to use an expression, use `bindValue` instead of `bindParam`. It doesn't bind to a variable reference.

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem